# add array to json file with no key

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have to make a file in JSON format which must look like the following:

xyz.json

```
[
    {
        "imagelist": "/oracle/public/oel6",
        "label": "test_higgs",
        "shape": "small",
        "name" : "/Compute-computecli1/computeadmin/",
        "networking" : {
            "eth0" : {
                    "ipnetwork" : "/Compute-computecli1/computeadmin/ipnet"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The array should be added in the JSON file without {}, and these curly brackets have to come inside the JSON array.

The code for

```
{
instances:[
        {
            "imagelist": "/oracle/public/oel6",
            "label": "test_higgs",
            "shape": "small",
            "name" : "/Compute-computecli1/computeadmin/",
            "networking" : {
                "eth0" : {
                        "ipnetwork" : "/Compute-computecli1/computeadmin/ipnet"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

is:

This code adds json array as a value to "instance" key, but I want to add json array without json key.

```
JsonObject ipnetwork = new JsonObject();
ipnetwork.addProperty("ipnetwork", ipNetworkName);

JsonObject interface_type = new JsonObject();
interface_type.add("eth0", ipnetwork);

JsonObject instance = new JsonObject();
instance.addProperty(imageListCmdText, "/oracle/public/oel6");
instance.addProperty("label","test_higgs");
instance.addProperty("shape","small");
instance.addProperty("name","/"+customerName);
instance.add("networking",interface_type);

JsonArray instances = new JsonArray();
instances.add(instance);

JsonObject launch_plan = new JsonObject();
launch_plan.add("instances", instances);
```

Please tell how does this code has to be changed in order to get the output asked above.

Comment: Yes? And what have you tried doing so far? Where is your code and what are the issues you are having with it?

Comment: {
instance: [
                {
                    "imagelist": "/oracle/public/oel6",
                    "label": "test_higgs",
                    "shape": "small",
                    "name" : "/Compute-computecli1/computeadmin/",
                    "networking" : {
                        "eth0" : {
                                "ipnetwork" : "/Compute-computecli1/computeadmin/ipnet"
                        }
                    }
                }
]
}

Comment: i tried code for this!! but i am not getting how to get the above code mentioned in the question

Comment: There is no code in the question, that is just (part of) a JSON. You need to show your code and ask a specific question you have trouble with if you want to get help. (As is this question is just too broad and off-topic for SO)

Comment: added code in the question please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
JsonObject launch_plan = new JsonObject();
launch_plan.add("instances", instances);
```

These two lines create the JSON object with curly braces. You don't need them, you can just remove them and use `instances`, which doesn't have curly braces as it's a json **array** and not a json object.

```
JsonObject ipnetwork = new JsonObject();
ipnetwork.addProperty("ipnetwork", ipNetworkName);

JsonObject interface_type = new JsonObject();
interface_type.add("eth0", ipnetwork);

JsonObject instance = new JsonObject();
instance.addProperty(imageListCmdText, "/oracle/public/oel6");
instance.addProperty("label","test_higgs");
instance.addProperty("shape","small");
instance.addProperty("name","/"+customerName);
instance.add("networking",interface_type);

JsonArray instances = new JsonArray();
instances.add(instance);

// not needed
//JsonObject launch_plan = new JsonObject();
//launch_plan.add("instances", instances);
```

Comment: OP may (or may not) also have to modify the code for writing the created JSON array to file (depending on how it is implemented right now, it's not shown in the provided code)

Comment: @YashaJadwani I included it.

Comment: @UnholySheep I totally agree! In this case we need the OP to edit the question